# Removing content of a var

Tags: javascript

I want to delete automatic the content of a string when it reaches 14 characters.

```
if(txt.length > 14){
    alert("");
    var res=texto.replace(texto.length," ");
    alert(res);
}
```

I tried to make a replace but it fails, any ideas?

Comment: You want to delete the entire thing, or just the overflowing characters ?

Comment: Why don't you just assign `""` to the variable?

Comment: i want to delete the full content of the string when reaches 14

Comment: `replace(text.length, " ")` is going to be something like `replace(42, " ")`, which makes no sense. `replace(string_to_find, new_string_to_replace_with)`. unless you've got the characters `4` and `2` in your string, you aren't replacing anything.

Comment: What's the purpose of the 3 variables? You have `txt`, `res`, and `texto`. What do they all mean?

Answer (score 5):

Your example code is very confusing as it doesn't really say what is being replaced where, but stating the obvious (as mentioned in the comments):

```
var txt = "some long text maybe?";

if(txt.length > 14){
    txt = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to completely empty the variable value you can do this:

```
var someText = "this string is longer than 14 characters";

if(someText.length > 14){
    someText = "";
}
```

If you want to remove any overflowing characters, you can simply create a [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) of that variable from 0 to where you want it to end:

```
var someText = "this string is longer than 14 characters";

if(someText.length > 14){
    someText = someText.substr(0, 14);
}
```

Alternatively, you can [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp) the string instead:

```
var someText = "this string is longer than 14 characters";

if(someText.length > 14){
    someText = someText.slice(0, 14);
}
```

Comment: The funniest thing about this answer is that is uses the EXACT same string as mine!  Haha...

Comment: @durbnpoisn Hahahahah that's so weird, great minds think alike ;)

Comment: Is there a way to remove the full content when reaches 14??

Answer (score 1):

Just use a substring that only shows the first 14 characters:

```
<div id="demo"></div>

    var thisString="this string is longer than 14 characters"

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = thisString.substring(0, 14)
```

The substring is (startChar, endChar)

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to zero out a string if it's longer that 14 characters, rather than truncating it, you can just set its value to an empty string.

```
var thisString = "this string is longer than 14 characters";

function thisFunction(string) {
  if (string.length > 14) {
    string = '';  
  }
  return string;
}

thisString = thisFunction(thisString);
```

Comment: This wont actually change the original string. You'll need to do `thisString = thisFunction(thisString);`. I believe strings in javascript are immutable

Comment: @JosephYoung Thank you! I updated my answer so that it actually modifies the original string.